# loading a directory lising with twig

Tags: php, twig

I am trying to use php scanDir to get all directories as an array and then use twig "for loop" in a template.

here is my index.php

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('templates');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'cache' => 'cache',
));

$dir = "movies";
$exclude = array( ".","..",".*",".php" );
$movies = array_diff(scandir($dir), $exclude);

echo ''; print_r($movies);

$template = $twig->loadTemplate('base.html.twig');
echo $template->render($movies);
```

and here is my twig template - base.html.twig

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Movies</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Movies</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for movie in movies %}
          <li>{{ movie }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the source code output from my browser

```
Array
(
    [2] => A Movie From Twentytwelve (2012)
    [3] => A Movie From Twentyfourteen (2014)
    [4] => Another Movie From Twentyfourteen (2014)
    [5] => index.php
)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Movies</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Movies</h1>
    <ul>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

as you can see the scandir is getting the array(but not excluding .php files). Also you can see the template is loading, but I assume I need to do something more to the array and also properly set variables in the template. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. array_diff compares full entries and does not work with file masks, as you want. Have a look at [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.pathinfo.php) to retrieve extensions of your files and filter them via [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-filter.php).

The second thing is, you'll have to wrap your `$movies` inside an array. Try 
`$template->render(['movies' => $movies]).`
Otherwise you would have numeric variable keys inside your template file (2, 3, 4, 5).

Comment: thank you nininho! I got it working now with

    echo $template->render(['movies' => $movies]);